# Помощь по Telegram Bot python

Tags: python, telebot

Всем привет!
Обрыскал весь инет и не могу найти где копать.
В общем и целом, сделал телеграм-бота на python.
И есть потребность, чтобы если пользователь какое то время не пользуется им, то при следующем сообщению бота или любому другому действию. Он автоматом запускал бот с самого начало.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: А что вы искали?) Ну вот как вы себе представляете, что должно произойти чтобы бот начал считать пользователя "новым" ?